# How to protect images from being hotlinked?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, hotlinking

I have tried the below code in htaccess to stop my images from being hotlinked, but it is not working.

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://www.example.com/" locally_linked=1
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://www.example.comm$" locally_linked=1
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://example.com/" locally_linked=1
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://example.com$" locally_linked=1
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^$" locally_linked=1
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|png|jpe?g|css|js)$">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from env=locally_linked=1
</FilesMatch>
```

Can anyone help me with how to prevent hotlinking?

Comment: You mean hotlinking. If you didn't want images to be saved at all you would have to keep it off of the Internet completely.

Comment: I don't know apache, but should the last one be locally_linked = 0? also, do you need a deny after the allow?

Comment: It will be easier that you don't completely block linking, instead display a Special Error Image using htaccess.

Comment: @ankit how to display error images

Comment: Regarding empty referrer, I came across sites which add <meta name="referrer" content="never"> to all their web pages, so all the hotlinked images would be requested with empty referrer.

Answer (score 2):

This will show a fixed image whenever its hotlinked. (That image may have a message that Hotlinking in not allowed...)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ /images/nohotlink.jpg [L]
```

It checks Refererr is not nothing, and referer is not matching mydomain then it responds with the image `nohotlink.jpg`.

To understand hotlinking prevention better see these SO threads:
[Apache .htaccess hotlinking redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126552/apache-htaccess-hotlinking-redirect?rq=1)
[Apache Hotlink Protection for Download Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775582/apache-hotlink-protection-for-download-folder?rq=1)
A Basic tutorial http://altlab.com/htaccess_tutorial.html

Comment: i have already tried all the help link given by you. Which is not working

Comment: @Ankit: isn't your code allowing hotlinking from a site at `http://mydomain.com.otherdomain.com`

Answer (score 0):

This disallows anything from hotlinking unless the referer is from `example.com`.

```
SetEnvIf Referer example\.com localreferer
<FilesMatch \.(jpg|png|gif|css|js|pdf|doc|xls|txt)$>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from env=localreferer
</FilesMatch>
```