# .png images not displaying

Tags: html, image, png

I have a issue of displaying .png images on web my web page. Other image types excluding .png just work fine. The issue is .png. The web site is located in a sub domain. In the root, a wordpress site is running.

In firebug, I can see a 403 error. But I can assure that I have set 0777 permissions for all images. It couldn't be a permission issue.

Rarely, .pngs are loading. But the second request gives a broken image. I have applied different cache removal techniques including `<FilesMatch>` directive in .htaccess, appending version attributes to image link, using # ...etc. But nothing works.

The most complicated point is that when copy & paste the image link in browser it shows the .png. However not within a web page.

Can anybody help me resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://app.hdwallkit.com/assets/img/information.png 
not only in webpage ,png can't open in directly either .
may be server not support png to host

Comment: you should read this https://support.hostgator.com/articles/403-forbidden-or-no-permission-to-access

probably you have to change file permission

Comment: I'm able to get the .png to load separate of your page at: http://app.hdwallkit.com/assets/img/hdwallkit.png and the mime type is correct `image/png`. But linking to it from this page gives a 403... I suspect some sort of external resource linking prevention may be in place?

Comment: This question discusses hotlinking prevention: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324226/how-to-protect-images-from-being-hotlinked

Comment: If that was a permission problem, why .jpeg images can display? All images are in same folder.

Answer (score 1):

Even I tried executing it in a browser. But the .png image doesn't showup for me.

Try changing the image folder permission to 755 or 644.

Comment: Img folder has been set to 777 already. Found that it always need to prepend http:// to image resource url when executing in the browser.