# Proper regex for .htaccess redirect and prevention of hotlinks

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I posted this on Reddit (r/learnprogramming) and someone there PM'd me and told me to come here, so here I am!

I have been trying to learn regex's and I suck at them still. I seriously have difficulty grasping the pattern matching. I am solid in other OOP languages so I figured I would learn regex and it just evades me.

I have downloaded EditPad Pro so I can practice as http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html suggests. I can get expressions to match bulk text, but I am trying to parse URL's and I keep missing.

Here is what I am trying to do. I am writing my own permalink .htaccess file as a proof of concept study, so I can hopefully use this is in future sites.

*I need to return the following dynamic content from a URL:*

**I need everything other than http:// www.domain.com/ or http:// domain.com/ or domain.com/:**

*(I am adding a space after http:// because of the limits on new accounts)*

http:// www.domain.com/asdjh324hj.jpg
http:// www.domain.com/asa45s.png
http:// www.domain.com/aser24hj.gif/
http:// www.domain.com/wer234dsfa/
http:// www.domain.com/k3kjk4
http:// www.domain.com/k3kasd4/

**The matched part will then be appended to:**

http:// www.domain.com/some_dir/som_subdir/some_file.php?querystring=$1

**But, I don't want any of these urls in the results:**

http:// www.domain.com/some_dir/some_file.php
http:// www.domain.com/some_dir/some_subdir/some_file.html

**And I need to prevent hotlinking to images in the image_dir:**

http:// www.domain.com/image_dir/some_dir/some_subdir/some_image.jpg (or png,gif,etc)

*Hotlinked images would be redirected to a page with the passed image as a querystring.*

So what RewriteRule regex would I setup to grab this? I understand RewriteRules and the flags, putting matched results into variables, etc, I just can't figure out what regex I should write to grab the actual result.

If this is too complex for RewriteRules, then please let me know as I am struggling here.

Usually I do these in PHP and would start with:
.com/[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+
([^/]+)/?$
Then do good 'ol substrings and checks. It's hacking it to death and I should be doing better!

I am currently going through the regular-expressions.info tutorials and am making progress, but I keep grabbing the wrong things too.

Thanks for any help you can send my way!

Update:  I was able to resolve everything with a ton of help and discussed more here:  [Mod_Rewrite conditions help for hotlinking but allow local requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451085/mod-rewrite-conditions-help-for-hotlinking-but-allow-local-requests)

Comment: Aren't these more than 1 question? A search for ['prevent hotlink apache'](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=prevent+hotlink+apache) gives (this)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775582/apache-hotlink-protection-for-download-folder]. Try searching for '[apache] rewrite clean url' and '[apache] rewrite exception' for the other two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need everything other than http:// www.domain.com/ or http:// domain.com/ or domain.com/:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
```

> But, I don't want any of these urls in the results:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/some_dir/
```

> The matched part will then be appended to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /some_dir/som_subdir/some_file.php?querystring=$1 [L]
```

So in all it should look something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/some_dir/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /some_dir/som_subdir/some_file.php?querystring=$1 [L]
```

Which will make it so when you request something like `http://www.domain.com/asa45s.html`, it will get internally rewritten to `some_dir/som_subdir/some_file.php?querystring=asa45s.html`. As for the hotlinking bit:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/image_dir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png|gif|jpe?g|bmp|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?domain.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /some_dir/som_subdir/some_file.php?querystring=$1 [L]
```

This checks that first the request is for something in the `/image_dir/` directory, then that the requested resource ends with a png/gif/jpeg/bmp/ico extension, then that the HTTP referer [sic] does not start with `http://www.domain.com/`, `https://domain.com/` or whatever combination of the 2. If all those are true, then it rewrites the request to the `/some_dir/som_subdir/some_file.php` file with the original URI as the `querystring` parameter.

Comment: You sir are a god among men!  Thanks for the fast response and more importantly, explaining it. I am checking it all out now.  One question, can I add as many of these as necessary: 

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/some_dir/ 

As there are multiple, or do I just tell it to disregard all directories other than the image_dir?

Comment: @user1666691 you can add as many `RewriteCond`'s as you like, just note that they only apply to the **immediately** following `RewriteRule`. As for multiple request URI's to exclude, it depends on whether you want to exclude or include, there isn't really much of a drawback other than readability if it does what you need it to do.

Comment: @user1666691 The rewrite engine loops continuously through all the rules, over and over again, until the URI going into the engine is the same coming out of the engine. You have to make sure that once a URI is rewritten, it won't match the same (or another) rule again, thus causing a loop, and apache will return a 500 error. I have no clue what specifically you are trying to do here.

Comment: My problem also is there are legitimate sub-directories as well:  domain.com/admin (we could do a direct call if needed to domain.com/admin/index.php).  These should not be applied which is why I wanted to segregate them out.

Comment: @user1666691 You should post a new question and include your rules, it's impossible to do this through comments.

Comment: Apologies, please see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396645/proper-regex-for-htaccess-internal-redirect-and-url-shortening