# Proper regex for .htaccess internal redirect and url shortening

Tags: regex, .htaccess, apache2

Based on this thread:  [Proper regex for .htaccess redirect and prevention of hotlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394494/proper-regex-for-htaccess-redirect-and-prevention-of-hotlinks)

I am asking a more focused question (hotlinking is solved).

I am doing an image host project and am encoding image names.  I need to provide a short url for the users to access their images.  The following should be internally redirected:

domain.com/hsh1h.jpg (or other images extensions)
domain.com/hsh1h

These would be internally redirects to:
domain.com/image.php?query=hsh1h.jpg
domain.com/image.php?query=hsh1h

The issue is that the following url's should not be redirected:

domain.com/admin
domain.com/admin/index.php

I apologize for creating a confusing topic earlier and thank you all so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
# these rules ensure you aren't clobbering legit requests (like to image.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# just in case, exclude the admin directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin

# rewrite
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ image.php?query=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and patience.  I am new to stackoverflow, but your patience and knowledge will definitely keep me around.  Hopefully, I can contribute to the community as you have!  Thank for the indepth solution!

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteRule (.*) image.php?query=$1
```

But this is blacklisting - in general I'd suggest to use whitelisting for such stuff.