# Mod_Rewrite conditions help for hotlinking but allow local requests

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I had hotlink protection working, so I thought, but not for when the referrer is local.

```
IndexIgnore *
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=10

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/image_dir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png|gif|jpe?g)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?domain.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /some_dir/some_file.php?querystring=$1 [L]
```

What I need is:

If the referrer is not from my site on any image request on the site, then redirect to the page with what image the user is requesting.

If the referrer is from my site and the request is for any image in the image_dir, then redirect, otherwise do not.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:  Here is the full file to help:

```
## Default .htaccess file
IndexIgnore *
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=10

# your rules were looping before, that's bad, this will stop it
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# redirect the browser back to the referring page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/img/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png|gif|jpe?g)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?domain.com/
RewriteRule ^ %{HTTP_REFERER} [L,R]

# rewrite the request to the handler
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/img/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png|gif|jpe?g)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://(www\.)?domain.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /img/index.php?img_hash=$1 [L]


## Do pretty permalinks for our images
# these rules ensure you aren't clobbering legit requests (like to image.php) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

# just in case, exclude the admin directory 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC] 

# rewrite 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /display_image.php?img_hash=$1 [L]
```

Everything works exactly like I want except hotlinking:

```
domain.com/t4hd -> domain.com/display_image.php?img_hash=t4hd (WORKS)
domain.com/t4hd.jpg -> domain.com/display_image.php?img_hash=t4hd.jpg (WORKS)
domain.com/img/t4hd -> domain.com/img/index.php?img_hash=t4hd (WORKS)
domain.com/img/t4hd.jpg -> domain.com/img/index.php?img_hash=t4hd.jpg (WORKS)
domain.com/img/123/456/789/t4hd.jpg -> domain.com/img/index.php?img_hash=t4hd.jpg (DOES NOT WORK)
```

I still have to allow all requests to:

```
domain.com/admin/index.php (WORKS)
domain.com/profile/index.php (WORKS)
```

Hopefully this helps clarify what is going on.  Apologies for not doing this in the beginning.

Comment: Do other `.htaccess` directives still work? Is `RewriteEngine On`, as you haven't included it in your snippet?

Comment: I have updated the post with more information.

Comment: What do you mean by "but not for when the referrer is local?" Do you mean you don't want your visitors to ever view your images without seeing it embedded in your page? No direct access for anyone to the "image_dir" directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using these rules instead:

```
# your rules were looping before, that's bad, this will stop it
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# redirect the browser back to the referring page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/image_dir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png|gif|jpe?g)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?domain.com/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule ^ %{HTTP_REFERER} [L,R]

# rewrite the request to the handler
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/image_dir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png|gif|jpe?g)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://(www\.)?domain.com/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /some_dir/some_file.php?querystring=$1 [L]
```

That is, I'm assuming this cryptic bit in your question:

> If the referrer is from my site and the request is for any image in the image_dir, then redirect, otherwise do not.

means:

"If the referer is from my site and the request is for any image in the image_dir, send the request to the some_file.php handler, otherwise don't do anything."

Comment: @user1666691 `domain.com/img/123/456/789/t4hd.jpg -> domain.com/img/index.php?img_hash=t4hd.jpg (DOES NOT WORK)` is not very descriptive, no idea what "works" or "does not work" even means in this context.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that if you try domain.com/img/123/456/789/t4hd.jpg it should redirect to domain.com/img/index.php?img_hash=t4hd.jpg which it currently does not.  It currently sends you to http://domain.com/var/www/domain.com/web/

Comment: @user1666691 Looks like there's a blank referer, I've edited answer and added a check for a blank referer `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$` above the redirect rule.

Comment: Awesome.  That fixed that but hotlinking still works, i.e. if the user goes directly to http://domain.com/img/000/000/158/test.jpg they get the image when they should be sent to domain.com/img/index.php?querystring=$1

Comment: @user1666691 Added the `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$` line in the 2nd ruleset, and the `[OR]`, so that either the referer is local or there's no referer at all, the rule gets applied and rewritten to `/img/index.php?querystring=$1`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16798/discussion-between-user1666691-and-jon-lin)